# Session in PHP re-adding item to cart when refreshing site

Tags: php, session, browser-refresh

I have the following function in PHP which adds an item to a shopping cart every time the user clicks on Add to cart.

The issue is that, if someone reloads manually the page after having added an item to the cart, a new item gets added.

Any tips to avoid this?

```
function addtocart($pid,$q)
    {
        if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;
        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
        {

            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['itemId']=$pid;
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart']=array();
            $_SESSION['cart'][0]['itemId']=$pid;
            $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);

        }
    }
```

This is how I call the function:

User clicks on add to cart:

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $lang['ADDTOCART']; ?>" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $itemId; ?>)" />
```

Javascript executed:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addtocart(pid){
        document.cartAdding.itemId.value=pid;
        document.cartAdding.command.value='add';
        document.cartAdding.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Page reloads and comes into here:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['itemId']>0)
{
        $pid=$_REQUEST['itemId'];
        addtocart($pid,1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What page are they manually refreshing? The 'add to cart' page?

Comment: How is `addtocart()` called?

Comment: [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: I just added the rest of the code

Answer (score 2):

You could put an if statement to check if the element has already been added. On top of my head, something like:

```
if (array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart']['itemId'])){ // check to see if product has already been added
 // put code statments here
}
```

Comment: What if the user wants to add the same item again? It wouldn't add?

Comment: If the user wants to add the same item, then he wants to add another quantity (or substract the quantity); thus you would manage that inside the if statement.